# No bonjour discovery even in TAP\Ethernet-bridge mode OpenVPN

Tags: networking, openvpn, bonjour, mdns

I have a remote printer/scanner on a network that is accessible to me via OpenVPN server tap running on Ubuntu host. IP printing is fine, its the scanner service i need using tools on my client machine (OSX 10.15.7 via tunnelblick), thus why i have set up an ethernet-bridge. **However, I am still not seeing the expected mdns packets needed to use the scanner via Image Capture, for example.**

**I am able to successfully connect to server:**

• Assigned IP according to server-bridge directive

• Ip is on the remote network in the same subnet as gateway and all other remote devices

• Remote router visibly registers my client as a 'connected device'

• While connected, all remote hosts (including the scanner) are ping-able from client

• Remote scanner service is broadcasting as expected, confirmed by running avahi-browse on remote server

So despite what appears to be a perfectly working connection in tap mode, issuing dns-sd -Z on my mac confirms that I am not seeing any new service, however i do continue to see local services being broadcast.

What I thought was the direct and relatively straightforward way of doing does not appear to be the case for me, frustratingly.

Local firewall is off to make sure, maybe packets are being blocked from the tap interface in some other way? or perhaps some client side setting on OSX that is unique in order for this to work? In any case help shedding light on this or reference to something else i may have missed is much appreciated.